# How to get the type information of the ktExpression using kotlin PSI?

Tags: kotlin, abstract-syntax-tree

```
class Baz {

}

class Foo {

    fun anotherAction() : Baz {
        return Baz()
    }
}

class Bar {

    fun doAction() : Foo {
        return Foo()
    }
}

fun main() {
    Bar()
      .doAction()
      .doAnotherAction()
}
```

Is there a way using kotlin PSI to get info about the type of the `Bar().doAction()` expression? I need to figure out that return type of `Bar().doAction()` or `doAction()` is `Foo` or that `doAnotherAction` is a function of the class `Foo`. Basically, I'm trying to get the types of the `KtExpression`-s

I have `BindingContext` generated (even though with some warnings) but trying to access the type info of the expression always returns null. I tried to use `getResolvedCall(BindingContext)` and `getCall(bindingContext)` but it also always returns null.

Also, accessing `references` and `reference` in the the above code expressions: `KtDotQualifiedExpression` and `KtCallExpression` also returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BindingContext` was generated properly, I was using the wrong file with psi Visitor that wasn't analyzed and so wasn't included in the `BindingContext` I used.